# ERROR: Overflow encountered in multiply from ipykernel import kernelapp as app

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a code which, given a set of points (a_i, b_i), calculates the lagrangian polynomial expansion and plots it. When I try to run the program, it doesn't work. Can someone help me?
The formula of the LPE is:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIJ6h.jpg)

My code is:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 

puntosx=([1,2]) #set of x points
puntosy=([4,5]) #set of y points

def legendre(x,n):
  i=0
  j=0
  L=1
  y=0
  while j<=n-1:
    if i<=n-1:
      if j!=i:
        L=L*(x-puntosx[i])/(puntosx[i]-puntosx[j])
      else:
        i=i+1
    else:
      y=y+puntosy[j]*L
      i=0
      L=1
      j=j+1
  return y

x=np.arange(0,5,1)
plt.plot(x,legendre(x,len(puntosx)))
```